# Java: find sum of 2d array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Ok, so this sounds simple. but its been playing with my head for a little while now.

I need to create a method which finds the sum of a 2d array of integers.

I need to create the method:

```
public static int sum(int[][] array)
```

this is what i done so far:

```
public static int sum(int[][] array){
int sum1 = 0;
    for (int i : array)
        sum1 += i;

    return sum1;
}
```

But I'm getting an error `'incompatible types required int[] found int.'`.
Anyone that can help me complete this challenge?

Thanks.
Edit:
an example array would be:

```
3 -1  4  0
5  9 -2  6 
5  3  7 -8
```

for now they will always be of this format (4x3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `array` is 2 dimensional, you cannot specify `int i: array` in the `for` loop. Modify your code like this:

```
public static int sum(int[][]array){
int sum1 = 0;
for (int[] arr : array)
    for(int i: arr)
        sum1+=i;

return sum1;
}
```

**EDIT**:
To store sum of each row, make use of an integer array.

```
public static int[] sum(int[][]array){
int sum = 0;
int sumOfRow[] = new int[array.length];
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    sum=0;
    for(int num: array[i]){
        sum1+=num;
    }
    sumOfRow[i] = sum;
}

return sumOfRow;
}
```

Comment: how would i add the values of each row and store their values in individual variables?

Answer (score 3):

The logic inside the method should be:

```
for (int[] i : array)
   for(int num : i)
        sum1+=num;
```

`i` is a type `int[]` not an `int`. The second loop is to enumerate over the array `i` enabling us to access the numbers in there and add it to the `sum1` variable.

---

Further, as of Java-8, you can accomplish the task at hand as follows:

```
public static int sum(int[][]array){
      return  Arrays.stream(array)
                    .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                    .sum();
}
```

Comment: what is the time complexity for this? is it still O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int sum(int[][] array) 
{
int sum1 = 0;
for (int row=0; row < array.length; ++row)
{
    for(int col=0; col<array[row].length; ++col)
    {
        sum1 = sum1 + array[row][col];
    }
  } return sum1;
}
```

more information can be found here: [Finding the sum of the values in a 2D Array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620491/finding-the-sum-of-the-values-in-a-2d-array-in-c-sharp)

logic is still sound

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` declared as `int[][]`, which really means an array of `int[]`. That is, elements of `array` have type `int[]`, which are themselves arrays (this is why `array` is a "2D" array). When you write a for-each loop, make sure that your types match up:

```
for (int[] innerArray : array) {
    // do things with innerArray, which is a 1D int[]
}
```

The full solution looks like this:

```
public static int sum(int[][] array) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int[] innerArray : array)
        for (int i : innerArray)
            sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not `+` an array directly, see [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8):

> If the type of either operand of a + operator is **String**, then the
>   operation is string concatenation.
>
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the + operator must
>   be a type that is **convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type**, or
>   a compile-time error occurs.

So, if none of the operands is `String`, the additive operator is only appliable for:

- Byte, byte
- Short, short
- Character, char
- Integer, int
- Long, long
- Float, float
- Double, double

### Solution

You can achieve this by nested loops:

```
public static int sum2D(int[][] matrix){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int[] array : matrix) {
        for (int element : array) {
            sum += element;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

or create another method to calculate the sum of 1D array:

```
public static int sum2D(int[][] matrix){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int[] array : matrix)
        sum += sum1D(array);
    return sum;
}

public static int sum1D(int[] array){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int number : array)
        sum += number;
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way of doing this would be to just use two nested loops, each of which covers one dimension of your two dimensional array:

```
for (int r=0; r < array.length; ++r) {
    for (int c=0; c < array[r].length; ++c) {
        sum += array[r][c];
    }
}
```

### Demo